# Only the top RewriteRule works

Tags: .htaccess

I have two `RewriteRules` that couldn't work together, each will individually work but when placed together only the toppermost work.

My directory structure: `http://localhost/project/sitepages`

The pages:

`http://localhost/project/sitepages/page1.php?name=pagename`

`http://localhost/project/sitepages/page2.php?name=pagename&id=pageid&name2=pagename2`

How I want the pages to be accessed:

`http://localhost/project/pagename`

`http://localhost/project/pagename/pageid/pagename2`

The `RewriteRule` I use:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitepages/page1.php?name=$1 [QSA]`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitepages/page2.php?name=$1&id=$2&name2=$3 [QSA]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.*` matches anything to it is obvious only 1st rule works.

You can use these 2 rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ sitepages/page1.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ sitepages/page2.php?name=$1&id=$2&name2=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks it worked. however when there is `/` at end of the URL my CSS style got broken. how do I fix that?

Comment: That is due to your use of relative paths in css/js/images. To fix add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`.

Comment: I apply this RewriteRule

`RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$`

`RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]`

Which I got from here: `stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url` 

It fixes the problem. And now before I apply the HTML you posted I commented the rules out and put up `/` and refresh the page and my css are intact. I don't know, I feel it's playing peekaboo with me.

Comment: Read a bit about `<base>` tag and then change your HTML source as suggested

Comment: Yeah it did, except that the folder `project` is ommitted. 

It gives this `http://localhost/[the page name]`

 and when I added it to the base like: `<base href="project/" />` the links became `http://localhost/project/project/[page name]`

Before it work I have to add `/project/[name of page]` before any url or url in  include/require.

Comment: It should be `<base href="/project/" /> `

Comment: Of course. My mind wandered a lil bit. `/project/` does the trick.

Another issue I forgot to mention,  how do I integrate pagination? At the moment my pagination work through:

 `localhost/project/ pagename?page=pagenumber`

 `localhost/project/pagename/id/pagename2?page=pagenumber`

how do I turn it to:

 `localhost/project/pagename/pagenumber`

`localhost/project/pagename/id/pagename2/pagenumber`